# Implementing Blazor Server-Side to existing Asp.NET 4.6.1 project?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, blazor, .net-4.6.1

I have been working on a project which uses Asp.NET 4.6.1 framework. 
It has been designed with webforms. Is there a way that I could implement Blazor Server-side to the existing project?

Comment: Not in the same project, no. Blazor Server Side is only hostable in ASP.NET Core. Web Forms is only in .NET Framework. You could however embed Blazor Web Assembly into your app. Or you could host Blazor Server Side alongside Web Forms and slowly move functionality over into it until you no longer need the Web Forms project. Perhaps using an IIS Virtual Application.

Comment: Impossible to add it to an ASP.NET 4.6.1 project. It has to be a new project and deployed separately.